# How to add Invoice in QuickBook using C# and Quickbook SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, quickbooks

I am completely new to QuickBook (Desktop) integration. I want to create an Invoice in QuickBook using the Quickbook SDK. I am following [C# .NET Application with QuickBooks Desktop Edition](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1568/c-net-application-with-quickbooks-desktop-edition.aspx) to crate my customer and invoice.

I can create customer but unable to Invoice.

Here is My Code :

```
ICustomerAdd customerAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerAddRq();
customerAddRq.Name.SetValue(Customer.Name);

IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
ICustomerRet customerRet = (ICustomerRet)response.Detail;

IInvoiceAdd invoiceAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceAddRq();
invoiceAddRq.CustomerRef.ListID.SetValue(customerRet.ListID.GetValue());

IMsgSetResponse invoiceResponseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse invoiceResponse = invoiceResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
IInvoiceRet invoiceRet = (IInvoiceRet)invoiceResponse.Detail;
```

I get `invoiceRet` always `null`.

Another Question is which property is user for `Invoice Number` in `IInvoiceAdd` ?

Answer (score 3):

When you get a response, you'll want to check the response status to see if the request worked. For example:

```
IResponse invoiceResponse = invoiceResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
if(invoiceResponse.StatusCode !=0)
{
    // There was an error with the request.
    string errorMsg = invoiceResponse.StatusMessage;
}
```

In this case, you'll get the error message: "The transaction is empty." which means that you need to add some items to your invoice to create a dollar amount on the invoice. Even though the OSR does not state that these are required, you'll still need to have them on there, even if they are zero amounts. It's the same as if you tried to create an invoice manually in QuickBooks without specifying any items.

Assuming you have an item setup called "Sales", your request would look like this:

```
ICustomerAdd customerAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerAddRq();
customerAddRq.Name.SetValue(Customer.Name);

IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
ICustomerRet customerRet = (ICustomerRet)response.Detail;

IInvoiceAdd invoiceAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceAddRq();
invoiceAddRq.CustomerRef.ListID.SetValue(customerRet.ListID.GetValue());

// Add these lines to your request
IORInvoiceLineAdd invoiceLineAdd = invoiceAddRq.ORInvoiceLineAddList.Append();
invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue("Sales");

IMsgSetResponse invoiceResponseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse invoiceResponse = invoiceResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
IInvoiceRet invoiceRet = (IInvoiceRet)invoiceResponse.Detail;
```

The field for the invoice number is called the RefNumber.